# How to make my interface on sending multiple mail in one column only?

Tags: php, html

I want only one fill only in my interface which is user can key in multiple email address. How to make my interface on sending multiple mail in one column only?
I want to combine all the references email in on column only.  To make my interface look better.

```html
 <tr>
                      <th>References Email 1</th>
                      <td><input type="text" name="referedstaff1" value="" placeholder="Enter a Email"/> <a title="Enter an appropriate email as references"><img src="css/images/h.png"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                      <th>References Email 2</th>
                      <td><input type="text" name="referedstaff2" value="" placeholder="Enter a Email"/> <a title="Enter an appropriate email as references"><img src="css/images/h.png"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                      <th>References Email 3</th>
                      <td><input type="text" name="referedstaff3" value="" placeholder="Enter a Email"/> <a title="Enter an appropriate email as references"><img src="css/images/h.png"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                     <tr>
                      <th>References Email 4</th>
                      <td><input type="text" name="referedstaff4" value="" placeholder="Enter a Email"/> <a title="Enter an appropriate email as references"><img src="css/images/h.png"></a></td>
                    </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: And where are you having problems? (Remove the unopened `</a>`s in that code)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on ux.stackoverflow.com

Comment: i want my form on references email only one fill that can key in many email address. My current form has 4 fills which is make my form not good.